# Unable to click on "New Application or Top Up" Text present inside <td> tag in watir/ruby

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-classic

I'm trying to click on the "New Application or Top Up" text that's present inside the `<td>` tag:

```
<button class="BIMG" tabindex="-1" id="T979" name="T979"style="border:0;background-color:transparent;left:14px;top:114px;width:193px;height`enter code here`:23px;z-index:2020; clip:rect(0px 193px 23px 0px);color:#28497b;">
<table class="T" style="top: 4px; left: 10px; width: 183px; height: 19px; font-weight: bold; font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial; color: rgb(40, 73, 123); text-decoration: underline;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
          <tr>
              <td style="vertical-align:top;text-align:left;">New Application or Top Up</td>
          </tr>
    </tbody>
 </table>
</button>
```

Comment: Can you please explain your situation better, I see you added the watir tag. Are you trying to click the element in you test? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Watir allows `String` & `RegExp` matching using the `:text` parameter:

`browser.td(text: "New Application or Top Up")`

`browser.td(text: /New Application/)`